# Junit Testing error

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I have an assignment on arrays I'm working on and one of the questions is to write a code for a histogram.

The method histogram takes a positive number n indicating the number of divisions in which the span of the data is divided, and returns an array of integers of length n, where each element of the array contains the count of the elements that fall into this
division.

For example, if the data is (0:5; 1:2; 2:4; 9:8; 5:1; 10:5), then its span is
10:0 (from 0:5 to 10:5).

histogram(4) would divide this range into four segments:
0.5—3.0, 3.0—5.5, 5.5—8.0, and 8.0—10.5.

Inspecting the data, we see that 3 values fall in the first segment, 1 value in the second, 0 values in the third, and 2 values in the fourth. Therefore, the returned value is an array of length 4 containing the values (3; 1; 0; 2) in that order.

Note that the sum of the elements in the returned array is equal to the number of
elements in the data array.

here is my code:

```
@Override
public int[] histogram(int divisions) {
    int[] range = new int[divisions];
    double segment = span() / divisions;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] <= (smallestElement() + segment)) {
            range[0] += 1;
        }
        if (data[i] <= (smallestElement() + (2 * segment))) {
            range[1] += 1;
        }
        if (data[i] <= (smallestElement() + (3 * segment))) {
            range[2] += 1;
        }
        if (data[i] <= (smallestElement() + (4 * segment))) {
            range[3] += 1;
        }
    }
    return range;
}
```

and here is my Junit test for my method:

```
@Test
public void testHistogram() {
    double[] data = new double[3];
    data = new double[]{0.5, 1.2, 2.4, 9.8, 5.1, 10.5};
    int[] dat = new int[4];
    dat = new int[]{3, 1, 0, 2};
    DoubleArrayStatisticalOutcomes x = new DoubleArrayStatisticalOutcomes(data);
    assertArrayEquals(dat, x.histogram(4));
}
```

the test is not passing. can someone tell me what I did wrong ?

Comment: Are you willing to tell us the error message?

Comment: arrays first differed at element [1]; expected:<1> but was:<4>

Comment: Run it through a debugger (or print the output of `x.histogram(4)` before the assert statement) and see what your function is generating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing all the histogram bins for each value. In your for loop, if a value is less than smallestValue() + segment, all the conditional statements are executed, not just the smallest it matches.

This makes your histogram cumulative. There are four elements total in the first two bins.

Add a `continue` statement in each `if` or make `if` 2-4 into `else if`s.

Your function also breaks down the moment you pass a value not equal to 4 as the tests are hardcoded. Try something like (untested):

```
double lowerBound = smallestElement();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < divisions; j++) {
        if (data[i] <= (lowerBound + (j+1) * segment)) {
            range[j] += 1;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all my tests passed now... thanks again